# Basic pitch shift using Stream methods in sounddevice module for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, audio

I really do not understand the correct format or code structure regarding how to implement the Sounddevice Stream methods. I want to create a basic buffer that writes my array data to be read in a callback almost in real time. I want to be able to change the freq of the sound wave via a threaded query that is integrated with the stream. I am trying to understand the basic API and how input to output works with streaming via Sounddevice.

https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/api.html

My lack of understanding of this API has me at a brick wall of knowing where to start. This is just for learning sound manipulation and applying effects to continuous sound without any audible cutoffs, kind of like a Theremin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after heavy API reading and some euroscipy videos I figured out the correct format for the sounddevice (portaudio fork) stream method. I also took some basic knowledge of threads and queues to create a rudimentary pitch shifter that is almost realtime. The pitch shifter will need to be changed and implemented with a knob. There will also need to be improved buffer speeds to be considered real time. Hope this helps out anyone wanting to just jump into manipulating sound without all the hassle!

```
def waveform(q):

    with sd.Stream(samplerate=RATE,blocksize=CHUNK,dtype='int32',latency='low',callback=None) as s:

        sps = 44100
        wave = signal.square
        t = .3
        atten = .015
        while True:
            i = q.get()
            freq = i
            waveform = wave(2*np.pi*(np.arange(t*sps))*freq/sps)
            waveform_quiet = waveform*atten
            wave_int = waveform_quiet * 2147483647
            s.write(np.ascontiguousarray(wave_int, np.int32))

q=Queue()
q.put(i)

p = Thread(target=waveform, args=(q,))
p.daemon = True
p.start()

#pitch shifter, increments of 10hz
while True:
i+ = 10
q.put(i)
print('Queues being stored')
print(i)
if i >880:
    print('Queues Stored')
    break
```